# android studio 1.0 adding proxy to startup script

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to run android-studio 1.0 on ubuntu using start up script but as i'm behind proxy the android studio gets stuck at "Fetching android sdk component information" and never downloads it. This occurs when i start android script from /bin/studio.h , at startup android-studio tries to download sdk but as i'm beyond proxy it won't download sdk.

I tried adding -Dhttp.proxyHost= and -Dhttp.proxyport in studio.vmoptions still doesn't fetch sdk. As it gets stuck in the fetching screen i'm unable to get GUI and hence not able to set proxy from GUI as well. Also get this error after starting " WARN - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Connection failed. Please check your network connection and try again."

Let me know if there is an workaround for this , thanks

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Go to the install location, open bin directory, edit the idea.properties, add below line to the file's end:

> disable.android.first.run=true

Then open android studio, set the proxy in configuration and close again.

Remove the line `disable.android.first.run=true` from idea.properties and open android studio again.

After this, you can work behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but like others have said even though the connection works fine the WARN still exists.

Comment: In my idea.properties didnt have this attribute, I just add disable.android.first.run=true and it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the install location, open bin directory,edit the idea.properties, add below line to the file's end.

```
"disable.android.first.run=true"
```

After that,when you entre the "Welcome to Android Studio",you may need to reconfig your android sdk and jdk location in Config/Project Defaults/Project Structure.

Answer (score 1):

For earlier versions of android studio.
Currently it has a UI for setting proxy.

As I posted here:

[Blog post: Installing Android Studio behind proxy](http://mayneax.blogspot.com/2015/01/installing-android-studio-behind-proxy.html)

> Navigate to the **android-studio/bin** directory
>
> you need to edit  **idea.properties** script to skip the initial set
> up page
>
> so run **nano idea.properties**  and add this line at the end of the
> script
>
> **disable.android.first.run=true**
>
> save the script and the run   **./studio.sh**
>
> On the window that appears go to **configaration>http proxy**  then
> set your proxy.
>
> Exit and then edit **idea.properties** file and remove the line you
> added
> **i.e sudo nano ideas.properties then delete disable.android.first.run=true** save and exit , then run
>
> **./studio.sh**
>
> You will be good to go now.